# Deleting None values in a 4 scale list using recusivity-- python

Tags: python, list

I'm new to the platform, and I'm trying to make an useful function for my program in python that uses a complex list, (a list of list of list of words to be more precise).
The whole problem is that None values can be at every level of this "4 scale list".

However, I've tried this:

```
def WipeOutNone(List):
    for i in range(len(List)):
        if List[i]==None:
            del List[i]
        else:
            if len(List[i])>1:
                WipeOutNone(List[i])
    return List
```

but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea how to fix it, or just find another way to do it?

Any answer is welcome :)

Comment: can you provide an example 4-scale list?

Comment: Wouldn't it loop forever with the list `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: what i mean with a 4-scale list is like a matrix

4scaleListe=[[["word1","word2",None...],[None,"word1","word2",...]...],...]

Comment: i don't understand how it would loop with [1,2,3]
when i started it it said there was an index out of range

Comment: the problem is that the list could also look like that:
[[["word1","word2",None...],[None,"word1","word2",...]...],None,[["word",...],["word",...]...]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice to have an example about your use case

But if I understand this correctly, consider a simple 2 nested list where `None` occur at the parent level or the child level

In this case you can remove None using recursion

```
In [83]: a = [1,2,3,None]

In [84]: b = [a, None, a]

In [85]: def rem_none(l):
    ...:     if type(l) != list:
    ...:         return
    ...:     l[:] = [i for i in l if i is not None]
    ...:     for e in l:
    ...:        rem_none(e)
    ...:

In [86]: rem_none(b)

In [87]: b
Out[87]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

This is a super simplistic approach, you can do even more powerful stuff with [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

Comment: You get the idea of what i want to do, but i tried the fonction and it didn't work for me, i guess im copying it wrong (i don't understand how the "return" works in your code), but thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried multiples times copy-pasting lines after lines, but i couldn't make it work. could you have forgotten some lines or something?

Comment: My bad! it perfectly works! You are my savior :D
Thanks ;)

Comment: @MarcPartensky could you accept the answer then please?

Comment: sorry about that, i didn't know this could be done ;)